# How to test if a controller method forwards the requests to a specific URL?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockmvc

In my Spring Boot application I have the following controller with a single method that redirects all HTML5 routes to the root URL**:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
  public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
  }
}
```

How should I properly test that it works as expected?

Calling the `content()` method of the `MockMvcResultMatchers` class doesn't work:

```
  @Test
  public void givenPathWithoutDotShouldReturnString() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/somePath"))
        .andExpect(content().string("forward:/"));
  }

>>> java.lang.AssertionError: Response content 
>>> Expected :forward:/
>>> Actual   :
```

** I found out about this solution from following [this Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#using-natural-routes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I called the `andDo(print())` of the `mockMvc` class I got the following result:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = /
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Here I realized that Spring doesn't treat `return "forward:/";` as a simple String result, but a URL forwarding (in a way it's pretty obvious), so the proper way to write the test is by calling the `.andExpect()` method with `forwardedUrl("/")` as an argument:

```
  @Test
  public void givenPathWithoutDotShouldReturnString() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/somePath"))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/"));
  }
```

The `forwardedUrl()` method comes from `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers`.